# Is it possible to decrypt files when using Xcode cloud?

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

Using Github actions I'm able to run a script to decrypt files using gpg. This doesn't seem to work in Xcode cloud (I guess because gpg is not installed there).

Is there another way to encrypt and decrypt files when using Xcode cloud for CI? Or maybe there's a way to install gpg in Xcode cloud?

E.g. I want to be able to decrypt my JSON cloud config files.

After a lot of searching I can't seem to find any alternatives or even discussion about it. Is there a way to do it?

Or is this a silly thing to do in the first place? Maybe there's a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can install gpg on Xcode cloud using homebrew.

I just added this line to my shell script before the decrypt lines and the build passed!

```
brew install gpg
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-custom-build-scripts for more info.